# awk checking for spaces in columns

Tags: regex, linux, awk

Using a fixed record length file and trying to check for spaces for a column from position 134 and length of 160 for all spaces
Here is what I have:

```
 awk file.test |awk '{ teststr=substr($0,134,160); if (teststr ~ /^[[:space:]]*$/) {print "ALLSPACES"teststr"end"} else {print "NOTALLSPACES"teststr"end"} } '
```

It always return the else part eventhough there are values on the teststr

```
NOTALLSPACESTHIS IS A TESTend
NOTALLSPACES              end
NOTALLSPACES              end
```

What is wrong with the awk statement /regex

Comment: @Barmar..thanks for helping format my question..Oppsie that is a typo.. ny command is with the ending : but still does not work

Comment: I tried your script and it worked. Don't forget that the column position `substr()` in awk is 1-based, not 0-based.

Comment: @Balmar, I tried it again and it worked.. thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typo was causing the issue.. updated the awk statement above with the correct answer

```
 awk file.test |awk '{ teststr=substr($0,134,160); if (teststr ~ /^[[:space:]]*$/) {print "ALLSPACES"teststr"end"} else {print "NOTALLSPACES"teststr"end"} } '
```

TYPE: the *$ in after the space

Comment: Don't put the solution in the question, put it in the answer.

Comment: What was the typo? You said the problem with the `:` was a typo in the question, not the real code.